# Bitcoin Wallet Crash Report

Tags: wallet

I was into bitcoin back when it started years ago, but over the years I got busy with other things and forgot about it until all the recent news. I was able to locate two emails from 2011 notifying me of Bitcoin wallet crash report. I think that was about the time I also switched phones from android to apple.
The below info is what's in the email sent to me. Will I be able to retrieve my wallet info from the information in this email? If so, please explain how I can access this wallet again. Information listed as (XXXXX) is identifying information I have left out of the email chain log. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

```
Date: Thu Nov 10 10:13:26 CST 2011
Version: 1.39 (55)
Package: de.schildbach.wallet
Phone Model: LG-P509
Android Version: 2.2.2
Board: thunderg
Brand: LGE
Device: thunderg
Display: FRG83G
Finger Print: LGE/thunderg/thunderg/(XXXXX):user/release-keys
Host: android-buildserver
ID: FRG83G
Model: LG-P509
Product: thunderg
Tags: release-keys
Time: (XXXXX)
Type: user
User: (XXXXX)
Configuration: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=18 uiMode=17 seq=25}
ScreenLayout: size 2 long 16
DisplayMetrics: DisplayMetrics{density=1.0, width=320, height=480, scaledDensity=1.0, xdpi=159.37254, ydpi=160.42105}
Databases: address_book webview.db webviewCache.db

=== collected at exception time ===

Total Internal memory: 209190912
Available Internal memory: 27512832

java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6831)
(XXXXX)
```

Contents of FilesDir /data/data/de.schildbach.wallet/files:
2011-11-10 10:13:26  files  [0]

- 2011-11-09 10:56:28  wallet (XXXXX)
- 2011-11-10 10:13:26  key-backup-(XXXXX)
- 2011-11-09 12:47:42  key-backup-(XXXXX)
- 2011-11-10 10:13:26  key-backup-(XXXXX)
- 2011-11-10 10:13:26  key-backup-(XXXXX)

Contents of CacheDir /data/data/de.schildbach.wallet/cache:
(XXXXX)

Answer (score 0):

Before doing anything I would make some extra copies of those files onto some other media.

I think you should probably be able to download the latest version of the "Bitcoin Wallet" for Android (less ambiguously known as the Schildbach wallet) onto a new Android device, copy the backup file to the device, and then use the wallet's features to recover from those backup files. Menu, Safety, Restore, specify file. You might need to know the password you chose.

If a password was set, the files will be encrypted. There are programs that can help to find a password if you have some ideas about the password. One is [btcrecover](https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover):

> Bitcoin wallet password recovery support for
> [...]
>
> - Bitcoin Wallet for Android/BlackBerry spending PINs and encrypted backups

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. Greatly Appreciated